# Update on dashboard

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, updates

Well, I'm working on a mobile application with ionic framework. In one of my views, the user can edit your name, password and also its image. For this I am using the CordovaFileTransfer plugin and it works great for me. I'm managing to change the image and all the data I need. But not even like getting to change the data in my database, update the application. Let me explain.

When the user changes their image or their data, the web service response returns a "status 1" if achievement make the change successfully and also the URL of the image and the new name change. This we have in localStorage variables and $ rootScope within my application which update once it receives a status one from my server but to return to my dashboard application that is not updated, I close and open the application again and reflected the changes. As a way to do it, maybe my question is very basic but that works for more than one person.

JSON WEBSERVICE RESPONSE :

```
Object {status: 1, photo: "www.google.cl/de5a0cc049d0f3c394befb83d2cb44e3.jpg", name: "Test"}
```

Code controller angularjs

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(encodeURI(server),image,ftOptions,true)
      .then(function(result) {
          var respuestaJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(result.response);
          if(respuestaJSON.status == 1){
            sessionService.set("user",respuestaJSON.name);
            sessionService.set("photo", respuestaJSON.photo);
            $rootScope.username = sessionService.get("user");
            $rootScope.photo = sessionService.get("photo");
```

sessionService :

```
.factory('sessionService',['$http',function($http){
  return {
    set:function(key,value){
      return localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    get:function(key){
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    },
    destroy:function(key){
     return localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },
  };
}])
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="dashboard-header">
    <center>
      <div id="home-avatar" style="background-image:url('{{photo}}')"></div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: try to surrond your code in the if section with a $timeout that will "force" the digest loop. 
If that not solveyour issue, paste your HTML also ;) maybe you have definied a one way binding

Comment: @aorfevre edit a small html code that is really occupy. What I wonder about what he said, you should leave a timeout function that was updating that? I do not understand very well